# Deleting exact match String from text file

Tags: java

I am trying to remove a specific string in my text file. Current code gets the line one by one until 50 is hit. I am trying to remove the string (EXACT MATCH!) in the notepad, but not sure how to do so.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:\\file.txt"));
            int counter = 0;
            while(input.hasNextLine() && counter < 50) {
                counter++;
                String tempName = input.nextLine();
                //perform my custom code here
                //somehow delete tempName from the text file (exact match)
            }
```

I have tried `input.nextLine().replaceFirst(tempName, "");` without any luck

Comment: You need to write the changed line back to the file if you need to see the change in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, You can do something like below using `java.nio` package:

```
Path p = Paths.get("PATH-TO-FILE");
List<String> lines = Files.lines(p)
              .map(str -> str.replaceFirst("STRING-TO-DELETE",""))
              .filter(str -> !str.equals(""))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
Files.write(p, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: It does not work for me. Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: OP has already tried with replaceFirst so how does this help?

Comment: provide the sample input and expected result.

Comment: Code is being executed, but it does not remove the string from my text file. I added a log to check.

Comment: @TarunVerma Thank you. Is there a way to remove the entire line instead of replacing it with nothing? Line still exists, need it removed if possible.

Comment: @beastil34 : You mean empty lines to be removed?

Comment: @beastil34 : Updated answer to remove empty lines.

Comment: @TarunVerma Yes! :)

Comment: @beastil34 Done. Give a thumbs up if you like the answer.

Comment: Thank you, works as intended. I have marked it as correct answer. Sadly I can not upvote due to not having 15 rep. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Below line replaces "the" with "**"

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("the", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tempName);
String repalcedvalue = matcher.replaceAll("**");
```